# Define entity in module and edit existing items

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to create a module which defines an entity (called "didyouknow") with two fields: ID and content.

I have set it up to create new items of this custom entity, but I can't get it to work for editing existing items.

I'm trying to reuse the same form (`didyouknow_item_form()`) for creating and editing, which works fine for creating, but for editing. The "%didyouknow" part in the URL is supposed to mean that the argument of `didyouknow_item_edit()` is a loaded entity object, but it isn't; if I output it within that function using `print_r()`, it outputs as "structure." This results in PHP outputting:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in didyouknow_item_form()

The code for the functions is below:

```
function didyouknow_menu() {
    $items['admin/structure/didyouknow/manage/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Did You Know item',
    'page callback' => 'didyouknow_add',
    'access arguments' => array('create didyouknow'),
  );
  $items['admin/structure/didyouknow/manage/%didyouknow/edit'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'didyouknow_item_edit',
    'access arguments' => array('create didyouknow'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

function didyouknow_item_edit($didyouknow){
  return drupal_get_form('didyouknow_item_form', $didyouknow);
}

function didyouknow_add() {
    $didyouknow = (object) array (
    'pid' => '',
    'type' => 'didyouknow',
    'content' => '',
  );

  return drupal_get_form('didyouknow_item_form', $didyouknow);
}

function didyouknow_item_form($form, &$form_state, $didyouknow) {
  $form['content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Content'),
    '#default_value' => $didyouknow->content,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  field_attach_form('didyouknow', $didyouknow, $form, $form_state);

  return $form;
}

function didyouknow_item_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $didyouknow_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
  field_attach_form_validate('diyouknow', $didyouknow_submission, $form, $form_state);
}

function didyouknow_item_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $didyouknow_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
  field_attach_submit('didyouknow', $didyouknow_submission, $form, $form_state);
  $didyouknow = didyouknow_item_save($didyouknow_submission);
  $form_state['redirect'] = "admin/structure/didyouknow/manage/$didyouknow->pid/edit";
}

function didyouknow_item_save(&$didyouknow) {
  return entity_get_controller('didyouknow')->save($didyouknow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in that code. First of all, you assume that having a didyouknow-id in the URL, is enough for Drupal to know where to get your object, the second problem is that your page argument is off.

This simplified code:

```
$items['admin/structure/didyouknow/manage/%didyouknow/edit'] = array(
  // …
  'page arguments' => array(1),
);
```

will pass on "structure" as an argument, *not* the %didyouknow id, nor a didyouknow-object, which is why you get an error about a "non-object". Argument indexing start with 0 => admin, so (as already mentioned by LToomre) you need to have:

```
'page arguments' => array(4),
```

It is also important to note that Drupal will *not* automatically know how to load your entity, you are required to provide the load function yourself.

As an example, look at the [epay module](http://drupalcode.org/project/epay.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/epay.module), which has a menu hook like this:

```
$items['payment/epay/callback/%epay_hash'] = array();
```

The named argument **%epay_hash**, is automatically mapped to a _load function:

```
function epay_hash_load($hash) {}
```

which takes the URL argument as parameter, performs the DB queries necessary to load your object, and then returns it.

Answer (score 0):

The result 'structure' come from the line 'page arguments' => array(1).

To pass in the %didyouknow value, you want to use 'page arguments' => array(4) instead.